# Issue with CKEditor Autogrow feature

Tags: jquery, ajax, model-view-controller, ckeditor

I am having an issue with CKEditor's autogrow feature,  I am using it in a page that uses MVC and ajax posts that return partial views,  when I fire certain $ajax posts (specifically ones that return partials without reloading the page) I am receiving the following error: Uncaught [CKEDITOR.resourceManager.add] The resource name "autogrow" is already registered.

I am wondering if there is a method to "un register" the autogrow feature and re register it after the process completes. Or if there is simply a way to avoid this all together other than a `location.reload(true)`.

Thanks for the assistance!

Comment: Are you sending down the full CKEDITOR js file as a script reference in your partial?

Comment: it's the full file, but it is being referenced on the main page containing the partials

Comment: could you provide a code example? and explain how you are setting the config, please

Answer (score 0):

you should create a folder in name your button in "plugins" folder for "ckeditor" , and in that folder create file "plugin.js", then you can but your code for your new button. for example   :
 - ckeditor/plugins/timestamp/plugin.js

that my code :

```
CKEDITOR.plugins.add( 'timestamp', {
init: function( editor ) {
    editor.addCommand( 'insertTimestamp', {
        exec: function( editor ) {
    editor.insertHtml( 'text' );
        }
    });
    editor.ui.addButton( 'Timestamp', {
        label: 'Insert Timestamp',
        command: 'insertTimestamp',
        toolbar: 'insert.0'
    });
}
```

});